# Using *ngFor in a custom ionic component does not work

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular8

I have a custom ionic/angular component which I pass data to `@Input() posts: Post[]`

```
import { Post } from './post';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post',
  templateUrl: './post.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post.component.scss']
})
export class PostComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() posts: Post[];
  post: Post;

  tests: [1, 2, 3];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.posts);
  }
}
```

this is the components.module.ts for my custom components:

```
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { PostComponent } from './post/post.component';
import { EditprofilemodalComponent } from './editprofilemodal/editprofilemodal.component';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [PostComponent, EditprofilemodalComponent],
  imports: [IonicModule, CommonModule],
  exports: [PostComponent, EditprofilemodalComponent]
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

for some reason, the directive *ngFor will not display anything:

```
<div>{{ posts[0].title }}</div>
<div *ngFor="let post of posts">{{ post.title }}</div>
```

but doing a simple `<div>{{ posts[0].title }}</div>` will work so whats wrong with ngFor?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you are not passing posts and input to your component.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass value to your child component like this.

```
 <app-post [posts]="posts"></app-post>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just restarted my server and now it's working! Think it was not recognizing the CommonModule in `components.module.ts`

Answer (score 0):

First check you have Poste in `ngOnOInit()`

```
 ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.posts);
  }
```

if not there so you haven't pass correctly then check

```
 <app-post [posts]="posts"></app-post>
```

pass hard corded value in your .ts file

```
this.posts = [{"title":"title 1"},{"title":"title 1"},{"title":"title 1"}]
```